# Make one array into the keys of a different multi-dimensional array

Tags: php

I want to take aa array like this `[2022, 'January', 1]` and use it as keys in order to populate the value of a different array, via a function. This is a very simplistic (recognisable) example using dates, but it might not be dates, it could be `['vehicles', 'cars', 'color', 'red']`:

```
public function addToDate($keys, $value){
    $this->allCalendarDates.$keys = $value;
}
```

```
addToDate([2022, 'January', 1], 'Happy New Year');
```

The `.` in the function is definitely not the way to do it, but it kind of illustrates what I need to do. I need it to be:

```
$this->allCalendarDates[2022]['January'][1] = $value;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use list() to extract the values and reorganize as keys.

```
public function addToDate($keys, $value) {
    list($year, $month, $day) = $keys;
    $this->allCalendarDates[$year][$month][$day] = $value;
}

addToDate([2022, 'January', 1], 'Happy New Year');
```

## Update

As you changed your requirement to a variable number of arguments you can go with references like this:

```
public function addToDate($keys, $value) {
    $data = [];
    $current = &$data;
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $current[$key] = [];
        $current = &$current[$key];
    }
    $current = $value;
    $this->allCalendarDates[] = $data;
}

addToDate(['vehicles', 'cars', 'color', 'red'], 'Happy New Year');
```

Comment: ok it's a nice idea to use the destructuring operator.. I didn't know of it before on php. But did you consider that allCalendarDates would need to initialize the associative array when a new key is introduced .. and it goes on in the chain.

Comment: It is enough to have the property `private array $allCalendarDates = [];` at the top of the class. As user is using it already, I assumed he did.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, I don't know that there will be 3 elements to the array, it could be ````['vehicles', 'cars', 'colors', 'red']````. I've updated my question, sorry it was not clear enough.

Comment: @user783322 Please look my answer update to your new requirements.

Comment: Oops, nearly perfect. The only issue is that ````[]```` will add a new key at the top level, not populate an existing one.

Comment: @user783322 Just put the extra logic you need into it. Also you did not specify that criteria what to happen with an empty array. Please do not change the requirements after an answer is placed.